# Python получить mac адреса

Tags: python

Как можно на python linux получить все mac адреса подключенной сети?

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
import ipaddress
import socket
```

Найдем адрес компьютера

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80)) # любой внешний адрес
ip = s.getsockname()[0]
```

Получим из него подсеть и пофлудим в неё. На арп ответят все, кто в подсети.

```
network = ipaddress.ip_network(ip+'/24')
for host in ip.network.hosts():
    s.sendto("hi", (host.compressed, 80))
```

Маки будут в таблице арп, для линукса:

```
open('/proc/net/arp','r').readlines()

#Out: 
['IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device\n',
 '192.168.117.105  0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:3c:a3:ed     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.10   0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:03:d4:59     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.115  0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:da:9b:45     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.112  0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:22:f7:2c     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.12   0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:03:d4:59     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.102  0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:f1:1f:e7     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.107  0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.9    0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:03:d4:59     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.138  0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.1    0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:07:1c:4e     *        wlp2s0\n',
 '192.168.117.11   0x1         0x2         XX:XX:XX:03:d4:59     *        wlp2s0\n']
```

или для виндовс

```
os.popen('arp -a').readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]

    clients_list = []

    for i in answered_list:
        clients_dict = {"ip": i[1].psrc, "mac": i[1].hwsrc}
        clients_list.append(clients_dict)

    return clients_list


def print_result(results_list):
    print("IP\t\t\tMAC Address\n-----------------------------------------")

    for i in results_list:
        print(i["ip"] + "\t\t" + i["mac"])


scan_result = scan("10.0.2.1/24")
print_result(scan_result)
```

Программа отправляет запрос на широковещательный адрес `scan_result = scan("10.0.2.1/24")`

Для того, чтобы работало для вашей сети, просто замените 10.0.2.1\24 на ваш ip - x.x.x.1\24.